# Correct HTTP Status Code when rejecting a request because User-Agent header is invalid

Tags: api, http, user-agent

I'm currently working on an HTTP based API. Our terms of use require the user to send an appropriate user-agent header (e.g. "-" is considered invalid). Now I'm not quite sure which would be the correct HTTP status the server should be responding with, if the request is rejected. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would fix the terms of use. This requirement doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why is that? The actual idea behind this is to collect some statistics, like how often the API is used by which app.

Comment: Niko - somebody who uses a UA that sends no User-Agent header will certainly be able to set it to an arbitrary value as well. How does this help with statistics gathering, except that you don't need to write code for "no UA present"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

400 Bad Request or 403 Forbidden would be the two I'd pick

Comment: 400 would be my pick. 403 is for logged-in users only

Comment: @TomBrinkkemper 403 is not only for logged-in users. The official meaning is _"The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated."_